# Would a $y$ axis affect the $x$ axis in a free body diagram?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram

Would a $y$ axis affect the $x$ axis in a free body diagram? like forces and all that can you add them or use them together. Or they do not interfere each other?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a free body diagram with whatever coordinate system you want. In general, we prefer cartesian systems where the axes are orthogonal to each other, and hence no component along the $y$ axis enters into the equations along the $x$ axis (and vice versa).

I have also seen free body diagrams in polar, cylindrical and even spherical coordinates. All of those have axes at 90° from each other also. But that doesn't have to be so. If convenient you can choose to resolve forces along slanted axes where you have coupling between the directions.